# R Stacked percentage bar plot with two factor variables - How to label the % inside the plot, without decimal cases?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, geom-text

How can I put the labels inside the plot without decimal cases, in both bars?

This is my code:

```
dados_gráfico_cursoanteriorsatisfação_PA <- PA_dados_desde_2015 %>%   
  filter(!is.na(qsd_3PA_curso_anterior_satisfação_rec)) %>%
  group_by(anoletivo_cat) %>%
  count(anoletivo_cat, qsd_3PA_curso_anterior_satisfação_rec) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), pct_label = scales::percent(pct))

dados_gráfico_cursoanteriorsatisfação_PA$qsd_3PA_curso_anterior_satisfação_rec <- factor(dados_gráfico_cursoanteriorsatisfação_PA$qsd_3PA_curso_anterior_satisfação_rec, levels = c("Very satisfied", "Satisfied", "Insatisfied", "Very insatified")) 

ggplot(dados_gráfico_cursoanteriorsatisfação_PA, aes(x= anoletivo_cat, fill = qsd_3PA_curso_anterior_satisfação_rec, y = pct)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity", width = 0.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(pct_label), y = pct), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), colour = "black", size = 3.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(y = " ", x = " ", fill=" ") +
  theme_void() + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black")) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black")) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm")) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(colour="grey90")) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "white"), panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "white"))
```

This is the plot I'm getting:

[image]

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you share a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: use `scales::percent` with `accuracy = 1` (and `scale = 1` if you have already number as percentage)